# Liquid for loop not working properly in Jekyll

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid

I'm using a liquid for loop in Jekyll to display page content based on this YAML structure:

```
work_left:
  isitgo:
    image: /images/isitgo.png
    caption: isitgoonair.net homepage
    description: a website
  disko:
    image: /images/disko.png
    caption: Disko
    description: a website
work_right:
  qfi:
    image: /images/qfi.png
    caption: qfi.im
    description: a website
```

This is the for loop:

```
{% for item in page.work_left %}
    {{ item.image }}
{% endfor %}
```

`item.image` will not result into the strings `/images/isitgo.png` and `/images/disko.png` being output.
If instead I just do `{{ item }}`, here's the result:

```
isitgo
{
    "image"=>"/images/isitgo.png",
    "caption"=>"isitgoonair.net homepage",
    "description"=>"an awesome website i made"
}

disko
{
    "image"=>"/images/disko.png",
    "caption"=>"Disko",
    "description"=>"that site"
}
```

What's causing this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are getting those results because of the way liquid parses associative arrays - which is what `work_left` is. On each iteration you get two items: the "key" and the "value".

I warn you that in some occasions this can give you problems. Notably, the order in which the items will appear is not guaranteed - isitgo could appear after disko. (This depends on the version of ruby you are using, as far as I know).

If you want to make sure that you always get the contents of `work_left` in the same order, you must use [list of associative arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Associative_arrays_of_lists) instead of an associative array of associative array, as you where doing. Here's how it would look:

```
work_left:
  - name: isitgo
    image: /images/isitgo.png
    caption: isitgoonair.net homepage
    description: a website
  - name: disko
    image: /images/disko.png
    caption: Disko
    description: a website
work_right:
  - name: qfi
    image: /images/qfi.png
    caption: qfi.im
    description: a website
```

Then the code to print them:

```
{% for item in page.work_left %}
  {{ item.name }}
  {{ item.image }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! Had tried a lot for half an hour, but didn't know abut `-` in YAML. +1

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the item created with a for loop has to be treated as an array.

So for my case:

```
{% for item in page.work_left %}
     {{ item[0] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Would output the first element of the returned (2-item) array, which is a string: `isitgo disko`. `{{ item[1].image }}` would access the `.image` property of the second item of the returned array, a variable, and it would display `/images/isitgo.png /images/disko.png`.